# Reprogramming NexStar for a Mac

Tags: external-hard-drive, filesystems

My NexStar External hard Drive Enclosure was originally set up for a PC. What can I do to make it work with a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Applications` => `Utilities` => `Disk Utility`, then re-initiialise the drive in Mac format (HFS Extended). Obviously this will erase any data currently stored on the disk, so you should back this up first if it is needed.

Comment: Doing this will wipe all data on it.